# Using a .js file in a .ts file in Angular4

Tags: angular

I would assume this would be a trivial problem, but doctor google hasn't cured me yet so I figured I'd come here.

I am new to Angular4.

I have a .js file (videos2.js) I would like to use, I cannot convert it to a .ts file - this is not negotiable. (It's part of the problem guidelines for the problem I'm trying to solve).

I have created a new component using:

```
ng g component videos
```

I would like to access a variable in the videos.component.ts file generated.

I have placed the .js file called videos2.js in the videos folder. And in the videos.component.ts file I have added the two lines:

```
import * as variable from './videos2'; 
declare var videos2: any;
```

And in the _dot_angular-cli.json file I have added the line:

```
"../../../../src/app/components/videos/videos2"
```

to inside the scripts tag.

However, neither method is working as the line:

```
import * as variable from './videos2';
```

returns an error about AngularJS not being allowed, even though I tried adding

```
"allowJs": true,
```

to both the config.json files. And the "declare var videos2: any;" isn't working either.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the error a 404 trying to load video2.js?

Comment: Do you include this file in your html

Comment: The error is: Failed to compile.

/Users/dalebaker/Documents/AngularProjects/clickViewPractical/src/app/components/videos/videos.component.ts (2,27): Module './videos2' was resolved to '/Users/dalebaker/Documents/AngularProjects/clickViewPractical/src/app/components/videos/videos2.js', but '--allowJs' is not set

Comment: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/ Please review code

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4591 please review link

Comment: I did not seem <script src="path/to/file/videos2.js"></script>

Comment: I've added a <script src="app/components/videos/video2.js"></script> tag to the videos.components.html file - still no dice

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way of trying to put jquery into typescript. but i have one solution that you can try which is save your js file into node modules and serve from that . if you are using angular-cli, then in scripts array you have to call the path.

Hope this will be helpful.